# node js code for copying file from s3 to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to take backup the file from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket. I'm using lambda function with nodejs for taking backup for dynamo DB. So i want to copy the files from s3 to another s3 bucket. Can anyone tell me the nodejs code for copying files from s3 to s3?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following code in lambda:

```
// Load the AWS SDK
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
        
// Define 2 new variables for the source and destination buckets
var srcBucket = "YOUR-SOURCE-BUCKET";
var destBucket = "YOUR-DESTINATION-BUCKET";
var sourceObject = "YOUR-SOURCE-OBJECT";

//Main function
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        
//Copy the current object to the destination bucket
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property
s3.copyObject({ 
    CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + sourceObject,
    Bucket: destBucket,
    Key: sourceObject
    }, function(copyErr, copyData){
       if (copyErr) {
            console.log("Error: " + copyErr);
         } else {
            console.log('Copied OK');
         } 
    });
  callback(null, 'All done!');
};
```

And Attach the following Policy to your IAM Role attached in Lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListSourceAndDestinationBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-SOURCE-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-DESTINATION-BUCKET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SourceBucketGetObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-SOURCE-BUCKET/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DestinationBucketPutObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-DESTINATION-BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score -4):

I feel it does not make sense copying files from S3 to S3. Generally, it should be copying S3 to Glacier instead with LifeCyclePolicies from S3. That's feature is already exists.

Comment: no.we want backup of data from s3 bucket another s3 bucket which is another region. please tell me about to write nodejs for copying file from s3 to s3